# Android Studio 3.0 - Gradle Sync failed for externalNativeBuild

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-studio-3.0

I am getting the following traceback when I am migrating to Android studio 3.0

```
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':celltower:compileExternalNativeBuildJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':celltower:externalNativeBuildCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :commonandroidutils.
     Required by:
         project :celltower
      > Unable to find a matching configuration of project :commonandroidutils:
          - Configuration 'debugApiElements':
              - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'externalNativeBuild' and found incompatible value 'debug'.
              - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
              - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
              - Required org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-api' and found compatible value 'java-api'.
          - Configuration 'debugRuntimeElements':
              - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'externalNativeBuild' and found incompatible value 'debug'.
              - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
              - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
              - Required org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-api' and found incompatible value 'java-runtime'.
          - Configuration 'releaseApiElements':
              - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'externalNativeBuild' and found incompatible value 'release'.
              - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
              - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
              - Required org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-api' and found compatible value 'java-api'.
          - Configuration 'releaseRuntimeElements':
              - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'externalNativeBuild' and found incompatible value 'release'.
              - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
              - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
              - Required org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-api' and found incompatible value 'java-runtime'.
   > Could not resolve project :wimtutils.
     Required by:
         project :celltower
      > Unable to find a matching configuration of project :wimtutils:
          - Configuration 'debugApiElements':
              - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'externalNativeBuild' and found incompatible value 'debug'.
              - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
              - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
              - Required org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-api' and found compatible value 'java-api'.
          - Configuration 'debugRuntimeElements':
              - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'externalNativeBuild' and found incompatible value 'debug'.
              - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
              - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
              - Required org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-api' and found incompatible value 'java-runtime'.
          - Configuration 'releaseApiElements':
              - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'externalNativeBuild' and found incompatible value 'release'.
              - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
              - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
              - Required org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-api' and found compatible value 'java-api'.
          - Configuration 'releaseRuntimeElements':
              - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'externalNativeBuild' and found incompatible value 'release'.
              - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
              - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
              - Required org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-api' and found incompatible value 'java-runtime'.
```

My build.gradle is here.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            ndkBuild {
            }
        }

        ndk {
//            abiFilters   "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
            moduleName "HelloJNI"
            //ldLibs.addAll(["android", "log"])
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false

            ndk {
                abiFilters   "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
                moduleName "HelloJNI"
            }
        }
        externalNativeBuild {
            ndkBuild {
                path "src/main/jni/Android.mk"
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypeMatching 'debug', 'release'

    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }
}

ext {
    retrofitVersion = '2.1.0'
    rxJavaVersion = '1.2.1'
    rxAndroidVersion = '1.2.1'
    okHttpVersion = '3.4.1'
    playServicesVersion = '9.8.0'
    fireBaseVersion = '9.8.0'
    daggerVersion = '2.7'
    appCompatV7Version = '26.0.1'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation "com.android.support:support-annotations:$appCompatV7Version"
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit1-okhttp3-client:1.0.2'
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofitVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:$retrofitVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofitVersion"
    implementation 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'
    implementation project(':commonandroidutils')
    implementation project(':wimtutils')
}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I moved out the externalNativeBuild outside of buildTypes and have put it under android. It started working.

```
android {
....
...
   buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false

            ndk {
                abiFilters   "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
                moduleName "HelloJNI"
            }
        }
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            path "src/main/jni/Android.mk"
        }
    }

    buildTypeMatching 'debug', 'release'
...
....
} // end of android
```

Comment: This produces an error: **Could not find method buildTypeMatching() for arguments [debug, release] on object of type com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension.**

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `implementation` with `api` only for last two project dependencies:

1. commonandroidutils
2. wimutils

Documentation states that:

The dependency is available to the module at compile time, and it's also available to the consumer of the module at compile time and runtime. This configuration behaves just like `compile` (which is now deprecated), and you should typically use this only in **library modules**. App modules should use `implementation`, unless you want to **expose its API to a separate** test module.

Reference: [Migrate to Android Plugin for Gradle 3.0.0](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#new_configurations)

Not sure, but give it a try. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this is possible. It looks like you have a mismatch between the Gradle plugin itself and its dependencies that provides the WaitableExecutor class.

However you mention Gradle 1.5 and this is a problem.

The plugin version 0.3 was compatible with Gradle 1.3-1.4 The new version release last week, 0.4 is compatible with Gradle 1.6+

Make sure you use 0.4 and the new Gradle version.